# PHP PDO using MySQL driver doesn't work - MAy be my code?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay I'm trying to convert MySQL request to PDO MySQL. I already do that before but I cn't get this one working :

```
    $query  = 'SELECT key FROM turl WHERE key = "'.$k.'"';
    $req = $db->query($query);

   if($req->rowCount() > 0) {
        $key = $row['key'];
    }
```

And here are PDO php extentions :

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_dblib.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird_interbase.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
```

I post here before ServerFault in case it my PHP code that is wrong.

By the way, here is the error :

Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in D:\Entreprises\Site web - Dev\xampp\htdocs\ushot\index.php on line 51

Comment: That probably means there's an SQL error occurring, so the result you get back is `FALSE` or whatnot. Try turning on PDO's error reporting.

Comment: Isn't `KEY` a reserved mysql keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the list at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html - `KEY` is a reserved mysql keyword.

So you need to quote it with backticks to get valid mysql query

```
$query  = 'SELECT `key` FROM turl WHERE `key` = "'.$k.'"';
```

Next: Since you're using PDO - placeholders is more preferred way to insert dynamic values into your queries:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `key` FROM turl WHERE `key` = :key');
$stmt->execute(array(':key' => 42));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much zerkms ! :) I really appreciate! 5/5 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to a different problem and just noticed your PDO extension list;
I had to comment out extension=php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll and remove the comment out from ;extension=php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll to fix a problem I had.

Then I found this statement on Php.net which seems to back up my action:

> mysqlnd is a new core library shipped with PHP. It is a PHP-specific replacement for libmysql. mysqlnd will be used to build the mysql, mysqli and PDO_MySQL extensions if libmysql isnt found on the system. It may also be used instead of libmysql even when libmysql is present. mysqlnd is recommended for all PHP installations for performance reasons.

here is the link to that statement: http://us.php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-extensions.php